# Compiling this OCR Library Code

Tags: java, image-processing, compilation, compiler-errors, ocr

I came upon this simple Library that someone wrote in java [GetImageText.java](http://abstractnonsense.com/portfolio/ocr/GetImageText.java) for OCR in images so i tried compiling it on my Ubuntu via terminal but i get several error as shown below in this paste :
[Compilation Errors](http://pastebin.com/69nWDYQ7)

Can Someone help me with it , it is absolute necessity that i test this code , its explanation can be found here

I think the problem is that i do not have com.sun.image.code.jpeg in my system, although java is definitely installed. Although I am not sure how to import this package without using an IDE.

Comment: Sorry could not add explanation in the brief due to repo points , here it is http://abstractnonsense.com/portfolio/ocr.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the library you are trying to recompile depends on INTERNAL classes<sup>1</sup>.  Portable libraries are not supposed to do that!

What has happened is that the class has been removed or replaced.  This happens from time to time, and that is the reason that people are not supposed to write code that depends on INTERNAL classes.

Solutions:

1. Bug the authors of the library to fix the problem.
2. Figure out which version(s) of Java that the library supports, and stick with those.
3. Find an alternative library that supports the version(s) of Java that you need.

Non-solution:  Compiling the library on an older version of Java and running on a newer one is likely to fail.  The class needs to be present at runtime, as well as at compile time.

---

<sup>1 -  Anything in the "com.sun" tree counts as INTERNAL.  Sometimes people have no choice but to have such a dependency.  However, they still needs to deal with the potential consequences for portability.</sup>

Comment: javax.imageio.* can replace this API but then I don't know how to edit code according to it .

Comment: additionally i have the .jar  file of this API which is deprecated but i don't know where to copy this to in order for my eclipse IDE or terminal to recognise it.

Comment: *" ... but then I don't know how to edit code according to it."* - Well I suggest that you get a colleague to help you.  StackOverflow is not a free coding service.  Or maybe, "skill up" so that you can do the work yourself.